# Ошибка обращения к памяти

Tags: c++, память, vector, конструктор

Нужно с помощью конструктора с параметром скопировать вектор. Выдает *Ошибку сегментирования*. Помогите разобраться.

```
      class matrix{
      private:
      int size;
      vector<vector<double> > mat;
      public:
      .....
      matrix(vector<vector <double> > matr, int s){
      size = s;
      mat.resize(size);
      for(int n=0;n<size;n++){
        mat[n].resize(size);
      }
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
          mat[i].push_back(matr[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы уже изменили размер, то зачем потом *добавляете* элементы, а не перезаписываете?

Во-вторых, лучше передавать большие объекты по ссылке, а не по значению.

В-третьих, я не пойму - вам нужно передавать в `mat` только часть матрицы `matr`? Просто если полностью - то проще всего

```
matrix(const vector<vector<double>>& matr)
:mat(matr){}
```

**Update**

А вот как выводить -

```
for(auto row: mat)
{
    for(auto x: row) cout << x << "  ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ну, или если очень хотите с индексами -

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < mat.size(); ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < mat[i].size(); ++j) cout << mat[i][j] << "  ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

И никаких `s` - размер вектора хранится в самом векторе.

Comment: `matrix(const vector<vector <double> > &matr, int   s):mat(matr){
          size = s;
          for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
              cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
          }
        }`

Comment: Я переоформил код но проблева возникает при выводе его на экран

Comment: Что такое у вас параметр `s` - что он содержит? Ощущение, что вы выходите за границы матрицы.

Comment: s - это размер матрици

Comment: Он вам не нужен! См. дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверка на то, что `s <= matr.size()` и `s <= mart[i].size()`
2. Делая сначала `mat[n].resize(size);`, а потом ниже по коду `mat[i].push_back(...) вы получаете матруци назмером s*2s. Замените последний`push_back`на`mat[i][j] = matr[i][j]`

Comment: Заменял, происходила таже ситуация

Comment: @ВладЛесной Штатный магический шар сдал в полировку, поэтоиму не могу угадать  на какую строку и какое сообщение показывает дебагер при падение, но подозреваю что проблема не в этом участке кода. Лучше сюда запостить более полную версию.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Дело в том что функция reserve() не создает размер масиву. И по этому функция vector.size() возвращала 0. Вышел из ситуции созданием с помощью resize()

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп! Где у вас в исходном вопросе `reserve`? Если бы там было `reserve`, я бы сразу вам сказал, что так делать нельзя. Но вы же использовали `resize`! Я же еще в ответе писал - "*если вы уже изменили размер*" - т.е. использовали `resize`.

Comment: Проблема была не совсем в функции. А в матрице коротой я передавал в функцию. Там то и был reserve